# Embed Typeform in React app

Tags: reactjs, typeform

How can I embed a Typeform form in my React app?

The embed code that Typeform provide doesn't compile in JSX.

This is a sample of the embed code:

`<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://sample.typeform.com/to/32423" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div> <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script> <div style="font-family: Sans-Serif;font-size: 12px;color: #999;opacity: 0.5; padding-top: 5px;"> powered by <a href="https://admin.typeform.com/signup?utm_campaign=ezQ2ub&utm_source=typeform.com-12183356-Basic&utm_medium=typeform&utm_content=typeform-embedded-poweredbytypeform&utm_term=EN" style="color: #999" target="_blank">Typeform</a> </div>`

Answer (score 8):

You can view Typeform documentation for embedding with JavaScript [here](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/).

And their official npm module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typeform/embed).

Use [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to trigger initialisation similarly to how you would initialise a jQuery plugin for instance.

```
import React from 'react';
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed'

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = null;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.el) {
      typeformEmbed.makeWidget(this.el, "https://sample.typeform.com/to/32423", {
        hideFooter: true,
        hideHeaders: true,
        opacity: 0
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={(el) => this.el = el} style={{width: '100%', height: '300px'}} />
    )
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a React wrapper component I created: https://github.com/alexgarces/react-typeform-embed

It uses the official Typeform Embed SDK under the hood. Basically you have to pass your form url, but it also supports other SDK options.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactTypeformEmbed } from 'react-typeform-embed';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ReactTypeformEmbed url="https://demo.typeform.com/to/njdbt5" />;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and getting the error: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-typeform-embed'. 'xyz_path/node_modules/react-typeform-embed/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: I followed the Widget steps on your GitHub repo and everything worked perfectly! Thank @Alex Garces

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Elise Chant's solution and using function based components, hooks and Typescript, this is what I come up with for my project. I did not want to install another thin wrapper on top of the official SDK.

```js
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

interface EmbeddedTypeformProps {
  link: string;
  hideFooter?: boolean;
  hideHeaders?: boolean;
  opacity?: number;
}

export const EmbeddedTypeform: React.FunctionComponent<EmbeddedTypeformProps> = ({
  link,
  hideFooter = true,
  hideHeaders = true,
  opacity = 90,
}) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    typeformEmbed.makeWidget(elementRef.current, link, {
      hideFooter,
      hideHeaders,
      opacity,
    });
  }, [link]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={elementRef}
      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', flex: '1 1 auto' }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript with react and you got this error just  make sure that `noImplicitAny` set to false in `tsconfig` file :
`"noImplicitAny": false,`